# Calling function or rendering component when back end analysis ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a Django-Rest-React app and I am facing some situations about parsing and receiving data back and forth.

In the front, the user needs to fill a form or select the desire analysis, and clicks the Apply button, which triggers the function selection() and also render a new component.

```
applyClick(){
        selection(); //POST method to back end
        this.handleClick_selection(); //closes current component
        this.handleClick_result(); //opens result component
}

selection() {
    var selected= [this.state.selected_1.value, this.state.selected_2.value]
    var selectedString= JSON.stringify(selected);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/selection/',
        data: selectedString,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("Data sent");   //This has to be deleted in afer development finish
        }.bind(this)
    })
}
```

This sends some data to the view selection, which runs a machine learning algorithm and dumps the result back to json:

```
def Selection_view(request):
    #the connection/request is completed, the success is returned 
    #to ajax before the machine learning method runs

    #runs the machine learning method
    data = Test(
         result=json.dumps(result).replace("'",'\"')
    )
    data.save
return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

The problem is that, while the machine learning algorithm is still running, my Apply button also opened the component that will display this data.

The component has a the following mount methods:

```
componentDidMount(){

    let result_parse = []; //result of the ml algorithm

        $.ajax({
            url: '/test/',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                data.map(function(d){
                    result_parse = JSON.parse(d.result), //d.result is the column in the json data that I want to parse
                });
                this.setState({ result: result_parse,); //result is the component state to handle the values
            }.bind(this),
        });

render() {
    return(
        {/* printing the result*/}
    )
}
```

When this last component loads and executes the ajax request, the machine learning algorithm is still running in the back end, so the answer to the request is blank or error.

I "solved" it momentarily by setting a timer to render the component, like this:

```
applyClick(){
        selection(); //POST method to back end
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            this.handleClick_selection(); //closes current component
            this.handleClick_result(); //opens result component
        }, 2000);
}
```

Because that way the POST method is made and the back end has "time" to return to json the correct values before the component is rendered.

But I know this answer is not ideal, is there a way to tell my result component to open only the json.dump(result) is executed?

Comment: Can you not close current component and show the next component inside your success function after receiving a response? Till that time you can show a loader

Comment: I can do that. But the problem is that the success response is received when the connection is established, which is the trigger for the machine learning algorithm to execute, rather than the response being dumped back to json.
So the when the success comes back to ajax, the machine learning algorithm is still running, and showing other component at that moment would also result in a blank call. I will edit the question for it to be more clear.

Comment: I guess you might want to start polling your server for when the process gets completed or use sockets to communicate from the server that it has finished @Lucas

Comment: @RagulParani Do you have a link explaining the implementation? Because that is what I need but I am not so familiar with this sort of communication.